# Validate only a specific field on a Livewire Component

Tags: laravel-livewire

I have a Livewire component which asks for different information in a multi-step form during sign up:

```
class Signup extends Component
{

    #[Validate('required|email::rfc,dns', as: 'email address')]
    public $email;

    #[Validate('required', as: 'verification code')]
    public $code;

    ...
```

In the function below I want to validate only $email:

```
public function checkEmail(): void
    {
        // Sanitize form values
        $this->email = UserService::sanitizeValue('email', $this->email);

        $this->validate();
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to validate a single attribute using the *validateOnly()* method:

```
 $this->validateOnly('email');
```